# Rigorous Proof for the Unique Existence of a Function in Introducing Adjoint in Linear Algebra, Considering First-Order Logic and Axiomatic Set Theory

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, set-theory, first-order-logic

$\newcommand{\linearmaps}[2]{\mathcal{L}\left({#1},{#2}\right)}$
$\newcommand{\linearoperators}[1]{\mathcal{L}\left(#1\right)}$
$\newcommand{\innerprod}[2]{\left\langle #1,#2 \right\rangle}$
$\newcommand{\powerset}[1]{\mathcal{P}\left(#1\right)}$

According to the rule of extensions by definitions in mathematical logic (link at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extension_by_definitions), to introduce a function symbol $*$ to denote adjoint, we need to prove the following theorem: for all $T \in \linearmaps{V}{W}$, there exists a unique function $S: W \to V$ such that for every $v \in V$ and $w \in W$,
\begin{equation}
\innerprod{Tv}{w} = \innerprod{v}{Sw}.
\end{equation}

My proof goes as follows. Suppose that $w \in W$. Then there exists a function $\varphi: V \to W$ such that for an arbitrary $v \in V$,
\begin{equation}
\varphi\left(v\right) = \innerprod{Tv}{w}.
\end{equation}
It is obvious that $\varphi$ is a linear functional. According to Riesz Representation theorem, there exists a unique $s \in V$ such that for every $v \in V$,
\begin{equation}
\varphi\left(v\right) = \innerprod{v}{s}.
\end{equation}
We may conclude that for all $w \in W$, there exists a unique $s \in V$ such that for all $v \in V$,
\begin{equation}
\innerprod{Tv}{w} = \innerprod{v}{s}.
\end{equation}
Next we would like to prove the follow set (function) uniquely exists:
\begin{equation}
S = \left\{\left(w, s\right) \in V^{2} \vert \textrm{for all }v \in V, \innerprod{Tv}{w} = \innerprod{v}{s}\right\}.
\end{equation}
The existence of the set comes from set theory (Axiom schema of specification, if I recall correctly). The uniqueness comes from the immediate previous conclusion. Finally we may conclude that there exists a unique function $S: W \to V$ such that for all $v \in V$ and for all $w \in W$,
\begin{equation}
\innerprod{Tv}{w} = \innerprod{v}{Sw}.
\end{equation}

Only with the above proof can we introduce the function symbol for adjoint. I am verifying if relating this problem to first-order logic and set theory is the only rigorous way to introduce math symbols.

---

Here are some of my thoughts. The proof itself is not too hard. However, it seems that to thoroughly understand why this proof is needed in introducing the adjoint concept and to prove the existence of a function, we need to understand set theory and first-order logic. This reminds me of the difficulty to educate students, especially those in engineering departments about true math. After all, it is very hard for general students (including me) to go deep to mathematical logic and axiomatic set theory to know the necessity of a proof before using a new concept, and to rigorously prove the existence of a function.

Comment: I am confused by the first few parts of what you wrote, is phi a linear map from $V$ to $W$ or a linear functional? Then the first thing you assume is the part which you stated you needed to prove? Also what is your question?

Comment: Sorry, typo as I copied it from my latex. Will modify it.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @CrabMan If this type of thinking relating to set theory and first-order logic is necessary.

Comment: What is the context that led to this question?  It would be highly nonstandard to take that detour into logic/set theory where you write “Next we would like…”. Instead, simply *cut out* the rest of the argument starting at “Next we would like…” and just say “We write $s = S(w)$”, or more commonly “We write $s = T^*(w)$” and end the proof there. The part of the proof you are asking about is excessively pedantic for teaching and I would advise that you not include it.

Comment: I guess that’s a softer question - I don’t think it’s necessary? I learned this proof and it made sense to me without knowing what “first order logic” means, or specifying any set theory axiom.

Comment: If you want a maximally rigorous way to introduce these definitions, or any other definitions at all, then indeed what you wrote is the main way to do that. Another way is to use type theory or a language that uses type theory (e.g. Coq, Lean) as your formal foundations of math.

Comment: Usually people don't do things so rigorously though.

Comment: Usually, one would simply write something like "If $\mathbb{F}$ is either $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, $V, W$ are inner product spaces over $\mathbb{F}$, and $T \in \mathcal{L}(V, W)$, then there exists a unique function $S: W \to V$ s.t. $\forall v \in V, w \in W\ \langle Tv, w \rangle = \langle v, Sw \rangle$. Such function is necessarily linear, is called the adjoint of $T$ and is denoted $T^*$." And then you prove that it exists, is unique, and is linear.